# Reading functions from one file to another in protractor JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

I have written a file with a number of functions that I wish to use across a variety of E2E tests. I have been trying to test this out and have found some solutions but none work for me.

This is how things stand.

In my TestingFunc.js file I have created the following:

```
var TestingFunc =  function() { 

this.login = function(Url) {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.get(Url);


            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.eeHook('login',null,null))), 300000);
            element(by.eeHook('login', null, null)).click();    
            element(by.eeHook('authenticationEmailField',null,null)).sendKeys(logins.International);

            element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(logins.password);
            element(by.eeHook('authenticationLoginButton',null,null)).click();  

            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(paymentFlow), 100000);

            paymentFlow.click();
            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(depositAmount), 7000);   

        };
};
```

and I am trying to read it in the following:

```
var url = 'http://master.mrgreen.avengers.zone/en-US/casino';
var TestingFunc = require("C:/Users/davbor.3DB/MrGreen Google Drive/LetsTest/TestingFunc.js");

describe("The security application", function () {


 var test = new TestingFunc();

it("will login to the page", function () {
    test.login(url);
});
```

});

Yet each time I run it I keep getting the error:

```
Failures:
1) The security application encountered a declaration exception
  Message:
    TypeError: TestingFunc is not a constructor
  Stack:
    TypeError: TestingFunc is not a constructor
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\davbor.3DB\MrGreen Google Drive\LetsTest\Testing.js:6:17)
```

Not sure what i am missing as I have even asked an in house developer to look at it without success.

Comment: Did you export your `TestingFunc`? `module.exports = TestingFunc`

Comment: yeah,m had it written as export and not exports and now it looks to be working well, Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> var TestingFunc = require("C:/Users/davbor.3DB/MrGreen Google Drive/LetsTest/TestingFunc.js");

1) You should not use full path. Use relative path to this file.

In your Testing.js require should look like this:

```
var TestingFunc = require("./TestingFunc.js");
```

2) You should 'export' your function:

```
var TestingFunc =  function() { 

this.login = function(Url) {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(Url);


        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.eeHook('login',null,null))), 300000);
        element(by.eeHook('login', null, null)).click();    
        element(by.eeHook('authenticationEmailField',null,null)).sendKeys(logins.International);

        element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(logins.password);
        element(by.eeHook('authenticationLoginButton',null,null)).click();  

        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(paymentFlow), 100000);

        paymentFlow.click();
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(depositAmount), 7000);   

    };
};
module.exports = TestingFunc;
```

Check more about nodejs modules here:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the export in place I am still encountering the same error.

Comment: the fix worked! I noticed that while reading through the suggested api, it is exports not export. Thanks a lot for your help! You really made my day! :)